# How to fix MySQL password error when installing Social Engine

Tags: mysql, installation, passwords, socialengine

```
"Please fill in the MySQL Password."

Mysql Host : localhost  
Mysql Username : root  
Mysql Password :
```

If I'm not using a MySQL password, then how can I fix this problem?
What can I change in install script of Social Engine?

Comment: lookslike social engine must have a Password for DB. So create a user in your DB with Password. Using the root user in applications is not a good idea

Comment: In some tutorial i saw "you have to edit the install script and remove the validation for the mysql password . so change in the php script having path ..INSTALL/FORMS/DbInfo.php"..then am not understand what should i change in DbInfo.php file

Answer (score 2):

How about just creating an user? It's safer anyway.

```
CREATE USER 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE, CREATE, ALTER, EXECUTE ON schema.* TO    'user'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Note:
I guessed the rights as I don't know what SocialEngine needs but I think these are all it will need.